# Selecting Radio Buttons from Links

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript from the "Javascript in 10 steps on less" book. On task 90 where the task is selecting  radio buttons from the link,i tried the code as exactly in book. There is the error that "TypeError: `document.myForm.myRadio` is not a function".
My code is as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function selectButton(button) {
    document.myForm.myRadio(button).checked = true;
}
</script>
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="First Button" /> Button 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Second Button" /> Button 2
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="selectButton(0);">Select First Radio Button</a><br>
<a href="#" onClick="selectButton(1);">Select Second Radio Button</a>
```

I myself see no error in the code. Anyone help me point out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There:

```
function selectButton(button)...
```

you are passing button as an argument to the function `selectButton`. Using `()` in this case is correct.

But there:

```
document.myForm.myRadio(button).checked = true;
```

`myRadio` is array of buttons. Indexes in arrays are accessed using `[]` syntax.

So it should be

```
document.myForm.myRadio[button].checked = true;
```

Demo:

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
   function selectButton(button) {
      document.myForm.myRadio[button].checked = true;
   }
</script>

<form name="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="myRadio"
value="First Button"> Button 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio"
value="Second Button"> Button 2
</form>
<a href="#" onClick="selectButton(0);">Select First
Radio Button</a><br>
<a href="#" onClick="selectButton(1);">Select Second

Radio Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct but use `[]` bracket instead of `()` like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script language="JavaScript">
function selectButton(button) {
document.myForm.myRadio[button].checked = true;
}
</script>
<form name="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="myRadio"
value="First Button"> Button 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="myRadio"
value="Second Button"> Button 2
</form>
 <a href="#" onClick="selectButton(0);">Select First
 Radio Button</a><br>
 <a href="#" onClick="selectButton(1);">Select Second
 Radio Button</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/priyank_s/rzL0zugd/)

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it is a dupe of mine which I posted half an hour ago.

Comment: @nicael:it's a javascript syntax which i corrected and not your's.so don't posted this kinda things here.please be professional

Comment: So if everyone will post the same answer with different wording, is it good? I repeat: your answer doesn't differ from mine at all.